# Inverse Laplace Using Heaviside Function

Tags: inverse-laplace

I have a function for which I need to both find the inverse Laplace transformation and sketch a graph. The function is
$$
F(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}-\frac{4}{s^2}e^{-s}-\frac{2}{s^3}e^{-2s}
$$
I've gotten as far as finding
$$
f(t)=t^2+(-4t+4)(u_1(t)-u_2(t))-t^2u_2(t)
$$
using the Heaviside function. I'm not sure how to convert this to a piecewise function. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverse Laplace Transform gives:
$$f(t)=t^2-(4t-4)\Theta(t-1)-(t-2)^2\Theta(t-2),$$
where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function. Now you should consider three cases: $t\le 1$, $1<t\le 2$ and $t>2$. Looking at different parts of the [function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E2-%284t-4%29Heaviside%28t-1%29-%28t-2%29%5E2Heaviside%28t-2%29):

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
t^2 : & 0\le t \le 1\\
t^2-4t+4 : & 1 < t\le 2\\
0 : & t>2.
\end{cases}$$
Since this is an Inverse Laplace Transform, we have to set $f$ for all $t\in\mathbb{Z}^-$ to $0$.